# Why does my node.js express code not call console.log()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How come "homepage requested" never gets output to the terminal console when I run `server.js` and go to `localhost:8000`? `index.html` renders fine

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

var port = 8000;
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use('/', index);

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("server started on port", port);
});
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('homepage requested'); // never executes
  res.render('index.html');          // always executes
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: the console log into node , goes to the terminal, not to the navigatot. Could be this?

Comment: it doesn't print in the terminal

Comment: Do you get the "`server started on port 8000`" line on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that shows up

Comment: You are looking in the wrong direction. `console.log` is working fine. Its you route thats not being called. Fix route and it should work

Comment: if the route is not being called then how come index.html always gets rendered? sorry, i'm new to node/express

Comment: How are you starting your application?

Comment: Works on my machine. Is something hijacking your stdout or console methods? Are you redirecting stdout?

Comment: I also can't reproduce this. It logs to the console. Are you using something like PM2 to start it?

Comment: Had the same "issue" it turned out I had a coy and paste error so I was loading another route instead of the one with the `console.log` ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

`console.log('homepage requested')` will print the message in the `terminal`, not in the `browser`. If you run your server with command line `node index`, and then open your page, in the terminal you will see the message.

Comment: doesn't print in terminal

Comment: @Don if it renders the index.html, so it must log also in the terminal

Comment: it does not. i've tried dozens of times and it never prints in the terminal

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the way you use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));`

If you take it out you should be able to see the `console.log`

It appears that if no `mount path` in the `app.use` and it sees a route with "/" (home route) it just serves up the static file from the `express.static`. It doesn't continue with any consoles.

A possible workaround for getting the console.log is to do a URL check in the `app.use` and that will only print out the home page.

```
app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url == "/") {
        console.log("just hompage")

    }
    return next()


}, express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")))
```

I think part of the reason why this is happening is that **`express.static` ends the response.** and you can't console anything after that. I think you don't even need the `app.get("/")` or `router.get("/")` because it by default if there is no mount path it work on "/" route. So it sends file automatically.

I think `express.static` runs on every route hit to check for static files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that it was writing my console log, but then generating a lot of other messages afterwards, so I had to **scroll the terminal back**. At first I thought it meant the server was restarting after a file save or crash, so I didn't bother to scroll back, which is why I started searching online. This is different from the way it behaved for me in the past, where my logs were closer to the end.

Answer (score -1):

You have an index file with the same name as the route.

Where you add the route,
     app.use('/', index);

This won't get called if the index.html file exists and is already served up (as the file has the same name as the route).

Change the name of index.html to index2.html.  Then do this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('homepage requested'); // never executes
    res.render('index2.html');          // always executes
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Your console should now show your message.

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended.

Comment: @wannabe, an easy way for you to test if this is the case is to comment out your `app.use(express.static(...))` line. Or move it to _after_ the routes.

Answer (score -2):

express won't output console.log to the terminal unless you set the DEBUG environment variable to express:*
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html